# MySQL datetime and Current Date Time function

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a novice to php's date() and strtotime, and have been attempting to find out the solution to this for the great portion of the day with no real solution (I've come close, but to no avail).

What I have is a typical database row with a 'submitted' column, which is entered via a submitted=NOW() (in datetime format).  I'm attempting to get the current datetime and find the difference between both values in "x Hours and x minutes".  To make matters a little more interesting my web server is an hour behind me in terms of timezones.  I've tried the "date_default_timezone_set('EST');" and it does help doing the straight date() function but obviously doesn't help me with my already inserted datetimes.

```
$lastEntryDate = date('l, F dS Y', strtotime($entryDate));
$lastEntryTime = date('g:ia', strtotime($entryDate.'+1 hour'));

$currDate = date('l, F dS Y');
$currTime = date('g:ia');
```

So, tried doing $lastEntryTime - $currTime, but that obviously gets messed up depending on the time of day (as it's in 24 hour format, I believe).

I've googled around and found a couple of posts on forums indicating using the 3600 (seconds in an hour), and I'm still trying to wrap my head around this.

Is there something basic I'm missing?  Or is this quite complex as I think it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$now = time();
$entrytime = strtotime($entryDate) + (60 * 60) //60 seconds times 60 minutes = 1 hour

$difference = $now - $entrytime;
$hours = floor($difference / (60 * 60));
$minutes = $difference - ($hours * 60 * 60);
```

Comment: This is great!  With your code above, it looks like it would return either the entire hours between the times or the entire minutes.  Here's a zinger, how would you find the minutes TO the hours between the times?  ex.  5 Hours and 34 Minutes

Comment: its a little more complicated but basically you take the difference between the two timestamps and then you find how many hours by dividing the difference by 3600 (60 secs * 60 = 1 hr) and then you take the remainder and divide it by 60 to give you the mintues. Anyway, I hope my math is correct there. Hope this helps.

Comment: Brian, `echo "$hours hours $minutes minutes";`. I computed both the hour and the minute part, though I didn't test. It's pretty simple math, you can write it out on paper if it's confusing. You have a number of seconds and get the number of minutes or hours that is equal to by dividing by 60 repeatedly.

Comment: Dan,  I echoed that out (echo "It's been ".$hours. " hours and ".$minutes." minutes since your last entry";) and it displays like this:  (It's been 1 hours and 2570 minutes since your last entry).  the 2570 increments up one every second though ...

Comment: I think I may have it ... $difference = $now - $entrytime; $hours = floor($difference / 3600); $seconds = $difference - ($hours * 3600); $minutes = round($seconds / 60);

Answer (score 0):

a solution that may be helpful to you is instead of using the MySQL now function why not make your submitted field of the INT type and then store a unix timestamp in it using the php time() function, then before inserting that into the database just add 1 hour in seconds to the timestamp. Then when you retrieve the data from your table you should be able to work with the timestamp and the php date and time function to create whatever timestamp you want. Here is a link on the php time() function which may help:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Comment: Thank you!  Definitely going to go through this.  Thanks!!